# Best practice for getting a derived class to implement a property?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Given a simple class hierarchy where each class is derived from an abstract base class.  Every derived class will need to somehow provide an enum "value" which the base class will use in certain base methods.
e.g.

Base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo
{
  bool SaveFoo()
  {
    switch (BarType){...}
  }

}
```

and derived classes

```
public class BananaFoo:AbstractFoo
{
  //barttype = fruit;
}

public class WhaleFoo:AbstractFoo
{
  //barttype = mammal;
}
```

There are a number of ways I can make sure that ALL classes derived from AbstractFoo implement a property "enum BarType"

```
public abstract BarType BarType{get;}
```

In each derived class I can then implement BarType to return the correct type, or add an abstract method to do a very similar thing.

```
public BarType BarType{get{return _bartype;}}
```

OR add a concrete method to return a field - then I need to remember to add the field, but it's a lot less typing (C&P)?

What is the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on what the correct way to do this is, but I've always used an abstract property on the base type (to force implementation), and then returned a constant from the subtype property.

for example:

```
public BarType BarType{get{return BarType.WhaleFoo ;}}
```

Comment: This is the way I've always done it...but suddenly had a "moment" when you come to doubt yourself! lol

Comment: I know that feeling: I had it while posting this answer ;)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to force derived classes to pass a value of Foo to the base class:

```
public abstract class A {
  private readonly BarType _foo;

  protected A(BarType foo) {
    _foo = foo;
  }

  // Does Foo need to be public or is it only used internally by A?
  public BarType Foo { get { return _foo; } }
}

public class B : A {

  public B() : base(BarType.Value1) {
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 as it's a viable option...however I will have many of these, so don't want a massive constructor if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only returning a single value of the enum for each child class, the best way I know of is to implement an abstract property in the base class, then implement it in each child class.

```
public abstract class A {
    public BarType Foo;

    public enum BarType {
        Value1,
        Value2
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public BarType Foo { get { return BarType.Value1; } }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, baldric just beat you to it.

Comment: Yep...took too long making it look pretty  :P

Comment: I've learnt the quick ones get an answer written and THEN make it look good ;)

Comment: That's true...sometimes I just get caught up in writing the answer though.  Don't forget to accept his answer!  ;)

Comment: lol, I hardly *ever* get there first, and the price this time was a less-pretty answer than yours... :/